# I off day this afternoon

Tags: sentence-construction, idioms

> I **off day** this afternoon.

Is "off day" use correctly for stating I working on morning but off on afternoon?

Comment: Where is the verb?

Comment: "I'm off this afternoon" or "I have this afternoon off" expresses your intended meaning. "I off Day this afternoon" is slang for "I will kill (someone named) Day this afternoon".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence is utterly ungrammatical.

There are **many ways** to say that.

> I'm not in the office after the noon. 
>   I'm here till afternoon, then I'm on leave 
>  I'm on a half day leave, post lunch *(this is specific though but works in most parts of India)*

Comment: I wouldn't use 'the' in your first example.

Answer (score 6):

We can say "I have the afternoon off" in British English.